# Override example for one field in DTO with OpenAPI

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I needed a different Instant format in all my dtos in swagger examples, so I've replaced schema for an instant like this:

```
var config = SpringDocUtils.getConfig();

config.replaceWithSchema(Instant.class, new StringSchema().example(INSTANT_FORMATTER.format(Instant.now())));
```

But I also need to have a specific format for some dtos. I've tried to add `@Schema(example = "2023-06-01T09:24:14.512125", type = "string")` for this field, but seems like this annotation is ignored because of my `replaceWithSchema()`.

How can I specify different examples for specific Instant fields, while having another example for the rest of the Instant fields?